# prev / next nav codes to be more efficient and flexible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have working codes that sets the Prev and Next URL based on the available pages numbers and the URL you are currently on.

My codes are way too long and not flexible at all. How can I make it more flexible and production ready?

http://jsfiddle.net/sunflowersh/ppDL7/5/

```
var currentindex = '4'; //updated based on the current index data 

var indexNum = parseInt(currentindex);
var currentURL  =      document.location.href.substring(document.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1, document.location.href.length);

var baseURL ="/en_US/";

var leftURL = "";
var rightURL = "";

switch(indexNum)
{
case 2: 
// if there are only index, index1, and index2

if((currentURL.indexOf("index.html")>-1)||(currentURL.indexOf("index.")>-1)){
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
 } else {
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
 }
break;
case 3:

// if on index3.html or index.html
// make the right arrow URL go back to index1.html

if((currentURL.indexOf("index3.html")>-1)||(currentURL.indexOf("index.")>-1)){
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-2) + ".html";
 } else {
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
 }
 break;
case 4:
if((currentURL.indexOf("index4.html")>-1)||(currentURL.indexOf("index.")>-1)){
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-3) + ".html";
 } else {
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
  }
 break;
 case 5:
 if((currentURL.indexOf("index5.html")>-1)||(currentURL.indexOf("index.")>-1)){
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-3) + ".html";
 } else {
 leftURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum-1) + ".html";
 rightURL= baseURL + "index" + parseInt(indexNum+1) + ".html";
 }
 break;
 default:
 // if no current index, disable the link
 leftURL= baseURL + "#";
 rightURL= baseURL + "#";

 }

 var leftArrow =$(".leftArrow").find("a").attr("href",leftURL);
 var rightArrow =$(".rightArrow").find("a").attr("href",rightURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a see at this http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/ppDL7/6/

Create a `index.js`

```
var baseURL = "/en_US/index";
var maxIndex = 4;
function updateNav(index) {
    if (index-1 > 0) {
        $('.leftArrow a').attr('href', baseURL + (index-1) + '.html');
    } else {
        $('.leftArrow a').hide();
    }

    if (index+1 <= maxIndex) {
        $('.rightArrow a').attr('href', baseURL + (index+1) + '.html');
    } else {
        $('.rightArrow a').hide();
    }
}
```

and, in every `index.html`, call `updateNav()` onLoad

```
<script>updateNav(2); // 2 current index </script>
```

If you need to parse the URL, try using RegExp `/\/index(\d+)\.html$/` (http://jsfiddle.net/steelywing/uex5m/)

Comment: Thank you, @Wing! I love the simplicity of the codes. One down side that our current system has is that index files are dynamically generated by Content Management System, and we can't put the manual <script>UpdateNav(#)</script>. That's why we have to use the common JS file to set the Next / Prev URLs. I believe based on your codes, I can inject the number dynamically get from the URL.

Comment: @user2326737 Add a RegExp URL parse =)

Comment: thank you so much! This is great! My long line of codes are now much shorter and flexible.

Answer (score 1):

MVC design would suggest rendering Next & Prev URLS on the server, which knows how many pages there are in total;

Or at least rendering a pre-prepared 'base URL' and 'pageCount' into JS variables, so producing a valid URL is trivial in Javascript.

An example in JSP:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var baseUrl = ${baseUrl};
    var numPages = ${numPages};
    var currPage = ${currPage};

    function changePage (delta) {
        var newPage = ((currPage + delta) % numPages);    // 0-based.
        var newUrl = baseUrl + newPage + ".html";
        // var newUrl = baseUrl + newPage;
        window.location = newUrl;
    }

    $(document).load( function(){
        $(".leftArrow a").click( function(){ 
            changePage(-1)});
        $(".rightArrow a").click( function(){ 
            changePage(+1)});
    });
```

If your page-numbers are 1-based, the % 'modulus' expression either has to be more complex (subtract 1 beforehand, add 1 after) or you can do an if statement.

```
    function changePage (delta) {               // 1-based PageNumber version.
        var newPage = currPage + delta;    
        if (newPage <= 0) newPage = numPages;
        if (newPage > numPages) newPage = 1;
        // ... as before.
```

Or via modulo:

```
        var newPage = ((currPage-1 + delta) % numPages) + 1;
```

Pick which you find clearest & most maintainable, if you were coming back to the code in 2 years time!

**[Edited]** If no server-side smarts at all, just put *constants* into the JS. You can also separate the constants/or calculation of base-URL, from the active part of the script.. thus making it reusable across several pages.

Comment: thanks for your comment and the example codes. It is clearly shorter and much simpler. Thank you! I have few questions.

function changePage (int delta) <-- does this simply mean integer number? What does this delta mean here and where this number gets assigned?

var newPage = (currPage + delta) % numPages; 

$(".rightArrow a").click( function(){ 
            changePage(+1)}); <-- does this take care of the situation if there are only index1 and index2, right arrow URL goes to index1.html?

Comment: Whoops, no 'int' required in Javascript. +1 is next page, -1 is previous page. Page numbering works best 0-based with % modulus operator.. but I'll edit the answer.

Comment: thank you! I will be coming back to the same code in one year :-) Thanks for your edits again. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your use case correctly, this should do what you want:

```
$(function () {
    var total = 3;        // index.html, index1.html, index2.html
    var currentIndex = 0; // index.html
    
    var base = '/en_US/';
    var pagename = 'image';   // for pattern: index<number>.html
    
    function getNavUrl(delta) {
        var newIndex = (currentIndex + delta < 0) ? total - 1 : (currentIndex + delta) % total;
        newIndex = (newIndex === 0) ? '' : newIndex;
        return base + pagename + newIndex + '.html';
    }
    
    $(".leftArrow a").click(function () {
        window.location = getNavUrl(-1);    // /en_US/index2.html
    });
    $(".rightArrow a").click(function () {
        window.location = getNavUrl(+1);    // /en_US/index1.html
    });
});
```

version with more detailed comments: http://jsfiddle.net/ppDL7/8/

---

#### Update:

After figuring out the exact recuirements, here is the final version. Also added index parsing from document.location.href:

```
$(function () {
    var total = 4;
    var base = '/en_US/';
    var pagename = 'index';   // for pattern: index<number>.html
    var currentIndex; // index.html === index[last].html 
    
    var href = document.location.href;
    
    function extractIndex(url){
        var regExp = new RegExp(pagename+'(\\d+)\.html$');
        var match = url.match(regExp);
        var index = match? match[1] : null;  // null if url does not match
        // interpret index.html as index[last].html:
        return (!index)? total : +index; 
    }
    
    function getNavUrl(delta) {
        var newIndex;
        if(currentIndex +delta <= total){
            newIndex = (currentIndex + delta <= 0) ? total  : (currentIndex + delta) % (total+1);
        } else {
            newIndex =  (delta < 0)? total - delta : delta;
        }
        return base + pagename + newIndex + '.html';
    }
    
    function setCurrent(index){
        $('.current').html('<b> ' + index + '</b>');    
    }
    
    currentIndex = extractIndex(href);
    
    $(".leftArrow a").click(function () {
        window.location = getNavUrl(-1);
    });
    $(".rightArrow a").click(function () {
        window.location = getNavUrl(+1);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ppDL7/12/

Comment: thank you for the example code! This is almost perfect. index.html is only available as a landing page. For the next / prev navigation, index.html will be skipped. So if total pages are index, index1 and index2, the Next URL of index2.html  will be index1.html and not index.html. (index1.html <--prev-- index2.html --next--> index1.html) I think this is the tricky part.

Comment: so as long as you are on index.html the following behavior?
index<last>.html <--prev-- index.html --next--> index1.html

Comment: so the complex comes from how this index.html works. index.html is really a duplicate of the index[last].html. this is done so the main website navigation doesn't have to be corrected - index[last].html has the most current info. when you are on index.html, then the navigation becomes -- index[last-1].html<--prev -- index.html --next--> index1.html. (not a good system, I know.. but there will be at least 2 indexes for a day and soon there will be more pages.)

Comment: I am still not sure if I understood you right, is this the desired behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/ppDL7/12/ ?
(on line 8 you can change the href to start from)

Comment: yes!! this is exactly what I wanted to do. Thank you so much! Seeing the great examples help me understand and optimize the codes better.